# RFID working with interrupts

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I recently created a rfid project with the sensor rfid rc522. I used the instructions mentioned by [this site](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/Aritro/security-access-using-rfid-reader-f7c746) and works perfectly. However, I intend this project to be battery supplied and I want to make the system use as low current as possible using the [low power library](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power). Well I need arduino UNO hibernate until an interrupt by the rfid is occured. Any proposals on how am I going to detect an interrupt by the rfid?

(PS) If there is any better battery saving library that can detect interrupts while keeping arduino slept, then feel free to propose it to me.

Thank you in advance.